# Radio buttons triggering an AJAX callback to load form elements are pre-selected after navigating back to form in browser

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

My form looks like this:

```
  $form['field_1'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Field 1'),
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#multiple' => FALSE,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_myform_ajax_field_2',
      'wrapper' => 'field-2-wrapper',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );

  $form['field_2_wrapper'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="field-2-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#weight' => 2,
  );

  if (isset($form_state['values']['field_1']) && $form_state['values']['field_1'] > 0) {
    $form['field_2_wrapper']['field_2'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Field 2'),
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#multiple' => FALSE,
    );
  }
```

The problem occurs when I submit the form successfully and move to the next page, and then navigate back to this form using browser back button and the `field_1` radio button is remembered by the browser. This means that the radio is already selected however in this instance `form_state['values']` is empty so field_2 does not display. From here the only way to get `field_2` to load via AJAX is to un/re-select the desired option in `field_1`.

I've tried the following solutions which failed:

1. Adding a JS file to `$form[#attached]['js']` to deselect any radio buttons on load, however this also gets loaded in AJAX calls. I'm not aware of a method to prevent this JS from running as a result of a traditional page load, but not on AJAX.
2. I've tried setting a `#default_value` on `field_1` however this has no effect.

Since writing this question, I've discovered a solution which I'm really not happy with:

I am checking for and adding a unique class name to the page body to check whether I've already deselected radios. If it's already there, then don't try again. This works, it just feels a bit dirty, so I'm hoping there's a more Drupally way to solve this?

Comment: That's how the "back" works in your browser. Your **browser is allowed to ignore server-specified defaults if it thinks it knows user input**, and returning to the state form was when you left it, if you decide to go back to it, makes perfect sense. If you have a purely HTML+CSS+JS solution you want implemented in Drupal, post it. If you don't, ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your instruction. I have a Drupal problem, and I'm looking for a Drupal solution, and something which is a little more elegant than adding a body class to prevent multiple calls to `Drupal.behaviours.myClass.attach()`.

Comment: No, you don't have a Drupal problem. If you will make a static HTML page with a form, it will behave exactly the same way - it will ignore defaults in favour of user input when you go back to it.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase that. I have an HTML problem, and I want a Drupal answer. I have also just found the solution, which I will post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a bit of searching I found this: http://codekarate.com/blog/drupal-7-prevent-duplicating-javascript-behaviors

Specifically it mentions ***Drupal 7 integrates the Jquery Once plugin into Drupal 7 core***.

Therefore I can modify my `Drupal.behaviours.attach` to the following:

```
  Drupal.behaviors.uncheckRadioButtons = {
    attach : function(context, settings) {
      $('body').once('deselect_radios', function (){
        $('input[type="radio"]:checked').attr('checked', false);
      });
    }
  };
```